# Access instance variable of an implementation class

Tags: java, interface

I have an `interface A` and an `implementation class B` for that interface. It's legacy code and now I am trying to return another variable from the impl class `B` without changing the method signature. I created an `instance variable` in class B. What's the best way to access it? Should I go through the interface A by adding a public getter function or directly call the getter in `B`?

Sample code:

```
public interface A{

}

public class B implements A{

   private int a =100;
   public int getA {
     return a;
  }

}
```

What's the best way to access `a` from `controller` class?

Comment: This question would be greatly clarified by some example code, covering both the structure described and the use cases that need to be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your context.

If your B's variable is universally / associated with the interface A (rarely) then you could create a getter method in interface A. Things like `Connection` in a SQL Driver interface, `numberOfLegs` in `Animal` interface

In almost other cases, a variable of implementation B is specific to that implementation only, so you should access it from B instance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's specific only to class B and won't be used by any other classes that'd implement Interface A, then you should limit it to class B, else if it'd be common use case to all implementing A then you should add accessor to Interface A.